# How can I trace the use of DLL imports that are used by static libraries that are linked in a C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, .lib

Apologies for the confusing wording in the title. I will do my best to describe the issue; please let me know if clarification is needed.

I work on a C++ DLL, call it Plugin.dll. I use the Visual Studio 2017 build tools. Plugin.dll depends on several static libraries (.lib) which are also maintained by my organization. There is both a debug and a release version of each static library. Each of these static libraries contains functions that depend on some 3rd-party DLLs. Therefore, a subset of these 3rd-party DLLs needs to be distributed with any software depending on Plugin.dll, depending on what functionality from the static libraries is used in Plugin.dll.

When I build the Plugin project in a debug configuration, the resulting DLL Plugin_d.dll depends on way more 3rd-party DLLs than the release version Plugin.dll. There are no differences in functionality between Plugin.dll and Plugin_d.dll that would require these particular DLLs to be included. The 3rd party DLLs are large and numerous enough that it is a nuisance to keep them in our repo and distribute them on the occasion we need to distribute a debug build internally.

I am pretty sure the reason for all these "extra" dependencies is design problems and unused code in the legacy codebase for the static libraries. The static libraries are not dependencies of anything other than Plugin. **My goal is to edit the source for the static libraries to remove these unnecessary dependencies that arise in the debug configuration**. But it's not that simple:

I use the VS command `dumpbin /IMPORTS:third_party_library.dll C:\path\to\Plugin_d.dll` to list the imported functions from third_party_library.dll. I get an output as follows:

```
    Section contains the following imports:
        third_party_library.dll
            183C7D0B8 Import Address Table
            183C80B18 Import Name Table
                    0 time date stamp
                    0 Index of first forwarder reference

                          0 ?FunctionName@third_party_library@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAUX2jfm@1@@Z
```

So I know that the only function from third_party_library.dll used by Plugin_d.dll is FunctionName. Since FunctionName is not directly called in the source for Plugin, I know that FunctionName must be somewhere along the possible call stack for a function from one of our static libraries that *is* called by Plugin. However, the output from `dumpbin /IMPORTS` does not tell me where/what the original call in Plugin is; therefore, I have to search the source for the static libraries and for Plugin to deduce where the call comes from, which is very time consuming. So my question is: **Is there a way to automatically trace the origin of the imports from third party DLLs back to the call in Plugin that caused the need for the import, without manually tracing every possible call stack?**

To complicate matters: The codebase for the static libraries is organized as a single Visual Studio Solution (.sln) with a Project (.vcxproj) for each library. However, there are several source files included in each library that are *not* included in the VS solution. I cannot add them to the VS solution because many of them have missing dependencies, naming conflicts, etc. that lead to compilation errors. So I cannot reliably use the IDE tools to trace references of functions within the static libaries' VS solution, because any references that are in files *not* included in the .vcxproj filters won't show up.

Comment: Probably the most straightforward way would be to run your app under windbg and set a breakpoint at the function in the 3rd party dll.

Comment: @Luke How can I do that if I don't have the source for the 3rd party DLL?

Also, I don't think this function will ever actually be called when I run the application (which is why I want to remove the dependency).

Comment: This is a C++ function, talking about .csproj project files doesn't help us help you.  In a C++ project you can use the linker's /VERBOSE option to make it chatty.  Project > Properties > Linker > Command Line > "Additional Options"

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I meant .vcxproj. Will edit the question. I only mentioned the project files to emphasize why manually tracing the calls would be even more of a chore.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried your suggestion. The verbose linker output tells me which .obj file from the static library contains the 3rd-party library call, but does not help me trace it back to a call in Plugin_d.dll.

Comment: If you remove the 3rd party libs from the linking phase, VS will aomplain about unresolved etcetc. In such messages At least you may read the decorated name of the offending functions, try to get the real names and search for them in your code.

Comment: @Ripi2 If you're talking about verbose output from the linker, the necessary functions from the import library for third_party_library were already built into the static libraries, so the linker has nothing to complain about as long as it can find the static library. I tried running an application dependent on Plugin_d.dll without third_party_library.dll in the same folder as Plugin_d.dll, with the VS debugger attached for Plugin_d.dll, but all I got was a generic "DllNotFoundException: Plugin_d assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)"

Comment: Another option is to load your plugin dll in IDA or GHIDRA and see where the function is being called from.

Comment: Also, you can add the static library source files to the project file and exclude them from the build process in order to leverage searching using the IDE tools.

Comment: @Luke The function that calls functions from third_party_library.dll is never actually called at runtime (which is why I want to remove the dependency on third_party_library). Thanks for the tip on the IDE search tools.

Comment: Just as an experiment, I removed all of the static library function definitions that can eventually trace back to a function calling third_party_library, rebuilt the static libraries, and now I can build Plugin_d.dll with no linker errors and no dependence on third_party_library! So all along there was no possible call stack involving third_party_library, which doesn't make any sense to me... I might have to make a new question for this topic.